# CSS Overlay not displaying

Tags: css, sass

I am starting my foray into Modals and the CSS I am using for the overlay, just doesn't seem to want to work. Any ideas what might be happening?

It is written in SCSS

```
@mixin transitionSupport($transition){
    -webkit-transition: $transition;
       -moz-transition: $transition;
         -o-transition: $transition;
            transition: $transition;
}

.modal-overlay{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 998;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    opacity: 0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    @include transitionSupport(1ms opacity ease);

    background: rgb(0,0,0);

    .modal-open{
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-overlay modal-open">
</div>
```

[Link to the codepen](http://codepen.io/pcmckinstry/pen/eBbWEK)

When I view the page itself, the page stays white. And I have no idea why.

Should the .modal-open{opacity:1} not override .modal-overlay?

Answer (score 1):

Change `.modal-open {` to `&.modal-open {` to match `class="modal-overlay modal-open"`.

As it's written currently, it's looking to match an element called `.modal-open` INSIDE `.modal-overlay`.

Comment: I guess that's what I get for not reading the SCSS documentation to the best of my abilities.

Comment: @CMckinstry Nesting is one of the biggest features of Sass/SCSS - it comes in handy a lot. Keep it up!